# Counting increasing sequences bounded by another sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Let $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ be strictly increasing integer sequences with $a_0=b_0$, and suppose that for some $N \geqslant 1$, $\ a_i \leqslant b_i \ (1 \leqslant i \leqslant N)$. Given $(b_n)$, how many sequences $(a_1, \; \dots, a_N)$ can there be?

The obvious thing is to try for a recurrence relation, but I'm not sure how to formulate it. Any hints greatly appreciated.

Or could anyone point me towards an explicit formula?

**Edit**  I think we can make this easier by letting $u_n=a_n-b_0-n$ and $v_n=b_n-b_0-n$; then

- $(u_n)$ and $(v_n)$ are increasing (but not necessarily strictly so);
- $u_0=v_0=0$;
- $0 \leqslant u_n \leqslant v_n$;
- The number of possible sequences $(u_1, \; \dots, u_N)$ is the same as the number of sequences $(a_1, \; \dots, a_N)$ above.

If we let $s_N(m)$ be the number of possible sequences with $u_N=m \; (\leqslant v_N)$ then in general $ s_{n+1}(m)=\sum_{r=0}^m s_n(r)$ and our answer is $s_{N+1}(v_N)$. I'm not sure where to take it from here, though.

Comment: Do you have an explicit formula for $N=2$?

Comment: @iamvegan Maybe this is where I'm going wrong. I reckon that $b_0+1 \geqslant a_1 \geqslant b_1$, that's $b_1-b_0$ possibilities, so for $N=2$ we have something like $\sum_{r=b_0+1}^{b_1} (b_2-r) =\frac{b_1(2b_2-b_1-1)-b_0(2b_2-b_0-1)}{2}$. That's your result with an extra term.

Comment: And I realise the inequalities should be reversed in that last comment. Excuse my crappy LaTeX :(

Comment: I found your edit useful. However you have to be careful. For example I think it should be $ s_{n+1}(m)=\sum \limits_{r=0}^{\min\{m,v_n\}} s_n(r)$. And if you denote $t_{N+1}$ as the number of all such $(u_n)$ sequences, then we have $t_{N+1} = \sum \limits_{m=0}^{v_N} s_n(m) \, (v_{N+1}-m)$

Comment: My answer for $N=2$ was originally wrong. Your answer is correct I believe.  Using your new notation we have $t_1=v_1+1$, $t_2=\frac{(v_2-v_1)(v_1+1)}{2}$

Comment: Also $s_2(m)=\min\{v_1,m\}$+1, if I am not mistaken. Using the recurrence can you calculate $t_3$ from there? Maybe we can find some reasonable formula?

Comment: @iamvegan thanks for sticking with this. I agree about the minimum of $v_N$ and $m$ - in the last paragraph of my edit I state (in parentheses) that $m \leqslant v_N$ (since $u_n > v_n $ is out of bounds). Subject to this, $s_1(m)= m+1$ , and $t_1=\sum_{m=0}^{v_1} (m+1)=\frac{1}{2}(v_1+1)(v_1+2)$

Comment: Please ignore the last part of that last comment - the edit timed out.

Comment: I disagree with your $t_N$ because it seems to assume that the sequence must end at $v_{N+1}$. As long as $u_N \leqslant v_N $ we're ok.

Comment: My claim is that $t_n=\sum_{m=0}^{v_n} s_n(m)=\sum_{m=0}^{v_n} \sum_{r=0}^{m}s_{n-1}(r)$

Comment: Sorry,that's clearly wrong - any formula must reference all the $v_i$ up to $v_n$  :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44585/discussion-between-floored-and-iamvegan).